# How to be sure to receive requests over the network? (for the staff in a shop for example)

Tags: ios, sockets, bluetooth, push-notification, multiple-monitors

If I want to make sure that a device receives a message, over the network, for an app used by sellers in a shop for example.
I heard push notifications are not 100% reliable, sometimes some of the notifications don't arrive, or not on time.

The app could be in a shop, where the staff communicate with one another, and there could be 10 devices connected. (ipad, iphones)

edit 1: I heard about sockets, is it the right direction to go?

---

EDIT 2:

I am not sure why a socket should be used, rather than a webserver for example, I found these 2 sentences (source raywenderlich) :

- You can send connected clients data whenever you want, rather than requiring the clients to poll.
- You can write socket servers without a dependency of a web server, and can write in the language of your choice : don't understand what the "dependency" is?

Does it also mean :
Sockets let 2 (or more) specific devices to connect one another in a private connection, compared to webservers where everybody could connect if there is no login/password?

---

**EDIT 3** : Maybe a bluetooth solution with MultiPeerConnectivity would be better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets, and push notifications in general, are only as reliable as the network the user is connected to.  If your looking to circumvent network reliability where a 100% success rate is guaranteed, in a Shop environment where users are in close proximity, you can look into [GKSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/index.html) as part of the **GameKit.framework**

Or you could look into Bonjour or client/service discovery protocols that makes the process of "knowing" peers in a network

I see you tagged Parse.com, again, the reliability of Push Notifications is highly dependent on the reachability, however, most issues that arise with Parse is dev-end related, not product related.

**EDIT** I forgot to mention [MultiPeerConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html)

Comment: Thanks soulshined, very interesting. you are right, multipeerConnectivity looks good. Can you choose between wifi and bluetooth? I am following this way I guess, looks like a good solution.

Comment: @Paul yes you can effectively switch between the two. Wifi might be better for range, however the good thing about this framework, is that you can daisy chain devices, say you have 10 devices and you device 4 is out of reach you can send the message through 1 to 8 to 6 who is close to 4 and they will recover it. That's a poor example, but range is a non issue. It was introduced in iOS7 I'm sure there are tutorials out there by now I haven't googled it I just remember it from an article after WWDC

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I found an example named "multipeerGroupChat", thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use TCP sockets, you are guaranteed the message will be delivered, and very quickly too.

However, the application would have to be open (and most likely in the foreground) to receive the messages. You can always have the server wait till the client connects to send the message.

I would suggest using a combination of both TCP sockets and push notifications (for when the app is closed).

Comment: I accidentally included an edit in your answer as opposed to mine. Please reject the alterations.

Comment: TCP sockets and Push Notifications' application are completely different.  Using Combination of those two just created chaos.  Especially with the given information, sockets should be used.

Comment: Thanks Harris and @user523234 , I edited my message, could you have a look?

Comment: I found more information thanks to soulshined, maybe a bluetooth solution would be better?

Comment: @Paul Webservers are built upon sockets, but as the two examples you found, sockets can do more. Using a web server approach, your app would have to request updates every so often (say 2 minutes). Using sockets, you can create a 2-way connection, and notify the client of any changes immediately, without the client asking.

I would also not suggest using bluetooth, because (while I am unfamiliar with the layout of your company/office), bluetooth offers incredibly short range and does not help your situation in any way that wifi cannot.

Comment: Thanks @HarrisC, ok, thanks. I am following an example with multipeerConnectivity (from ios7), which seems to do the connection for us, it sends data to the peers connected to the same session, either via bluetooth, or wifi. I don't know if this replaces creating your own socket server.